# While loop, WordPress find current id and get Next id

Tags: php, wordpress

Using while loop,

```
<?php
$current_id = get_the_ID();
echo $current_id;
$args=array(
  'portfolio-tag' => 'corporate',
  'showposts'=>0,
  'orderby'=>'post_date',
  'order'=>'ASC',
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      echo get_the_ID();
  endwhile;
} 
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

on my WordPress detail its look like.

```
308
368
420
980
1147
1157
```

these are portfolio items id. what i am trying to achieve, if i am current detail page id is 368 using this.

```
get_the_ID();
```

can anybody tell me how i can find current id in that while loop, and in that case 368 is on 2nd number. so i need 420 id because 420 is coming after 368.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`get_next_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) is for:

```
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_ID();  // display the current post ID

    $next_post = get_next_post();
    echo !empty( $next_post ) ? 'Next Post ID: ' . $next_post->ID : 'No next post';

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: that is not working in my case, i am updating my whole code above you can check. i am getting post which have corporate tag. and run a while loop so everything is on the post. i have to find next post id then current post id. but that should be in this while loop.

Comment: can you look my question again and  its more clear now. i have to find next id then current id. from while loop.

Comment: and while is showing all post id which have "corporate" tag i need just next one. url